# Gitattributes raise conflict when any changes in path

Tags: git, database-migration, merge-conflict-resolution

Is it possible to tell git to always raise a conflict during a merge if there are new files in both branches in a specific directory?

Background:
We create migration scripts for the database and commit that to the repo. The order of those migrations matters, so I want to make sure that if 2 developers create a migration v55, the 2nd developer will know he has to rename his migration to v56 when he merges his feature branch to master.

Comment: Shouldn’t there be a merge conflict already if two developers add a file with the same name independently of each other?

Comment: @mkrieger1 The file name is not the same. The order of migrations is derived from alpanumeric sort of files in the folder, so we prefix the files with AA, AB etc., but the rest of the filename is just a migration name. So two developers might add `A_AddColumnX.sql` and `A_AlterProcedureBla.sql`.